# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android-studio, retrofit

Soy nuevo con la librería retrofit y utilizo la versión 2.4.0
Tengo una aplicación en donde quiero mostrar la siguiente información Json en un ListView. Investigando encontré que yo espero una matriz pero recibo un objeto Json pero no he podido solucionarlo por mas que he intentado, ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

```
    [
        {
            "idalumno":"1",
            "nombre":"nombre 1",
            "direccion":"direccion 1"
        },
        {
            "idalumno":"2",
            "nombre":"nomnbre 2",
            "direccion":"direccion 2"
        },
        {
           "idalumno":"3",
           "nombre":"nombre 3",
            "direccion":"direccion 3"
        },        
    ]
```

Al correr la aplicación me encuentro con el siguiente error: 
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
y tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public class ApiClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://192.198.1.70:8080/ws/";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getApiclient(){

        if (retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Utilizo la interface

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("obtener_alumnos.php")
    Call<List<Contact>> getContacts();
}
```

Mi objeto Contacto

```
public class Contact {

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String nombre;
    private String direccion;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }
    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
}
```

El OnCreate de mi aplicación

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiclient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        retrofit2.Call<List<Contact>> call = apiInterface.getContacts();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contact>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<List<Contact>> call, Response<List<Contact>> response) {

                contactList= response.body();
                adapter = new NewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.list_item, contactList);
                ListView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<List<Contact>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("ERROR", t.getMessage());
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Realiza un GET con la url, usa por ejemplo https://www.hurl.it/ y revisa que respuesta obtienes.

Comment: alguna solución verdadera ? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error que comentas, indica que se esperaba tu información iniciara como un array (inicia con  `[` ) pero en realidad es un objeto (esta iniciando con `{`):

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Simplemente verifica que tu url http://192.198.1.70:8080/ws/obtener_alumnos.php al realizar un GET en verdad obtenga un Json Array, el cual debe iniciar con  `[`.

Comment: Eso dice pero en realidad la respuesta sí empieza con [

Comment: La estas imprimiendo?, Muestra tu código en una pregunta @ÁlvaroAgüero

Comment: UPDATE : no estaba recibiendo la respuesta del server, no era response code 200