# Erro: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: php, android-studio, retrofit

Estoy desarrollando una app haciendo uso de las librerías:

> ```
> -implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
> -implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
> ```

En donde quiero mostrar la siguiente información en un `listView`.

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Categoria": "90",
        "Descripcion": "Primax",
        "Precio": "10.55",
        "Banner": "Primax-90.jpg",
        "GrifoId": "2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Categoria": "84",
        "Descripcion": "Primax",
        "Precio": "12.29",
        "Banner": "Primax-84",
        "GrifoId": "2"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Categoria": "45",
        "Descripcion": "Primax",
        "Precio": "17.9",
        "Banner": "Primax-45",
        "GrifoId": "2"
    }
]
```

Mi Api Cliente es:

```
public class RetrofitCliente {

    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;


    public static  Retrofit getClint(String baseUrl){
        if (retrofit==null){
            retrofit= new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

La interfaz:

```
public interface IGasStation {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("getcombustible.php")
    io.reactivex.Observable<List<Combustible>> 
   getCombustible(@Field("menuid")String menuID);
}
```

Mi objeto `Combustible`

```
public class Combustible {
    public int ID;
    public String Categoria;
    public String Descripcion;
    public double Precio;
    public String Banner;
    public int GrifoId;

    public Combustible() {
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return Precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        Precio = precio;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getGrifoId() {
        return GrifoId;
    }

    public void setGrifoId(int grifoId) {
        GrifoId = grifoId;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return Categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        Categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return Descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        Descripcion = descripcion;
    }



    public String getBanner() {
        return Banner;
    }

    public void setBanner(String banner) {
        Banner = banner;
    }



    public  String getImageUrl(){
        return "http://192.168.76.1:8080/gasolinera/Combutibles/"+this.Categoria+this.Descripcion+".jpg";
    }
}
```

El Actividad:

```
public class CombustibleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    IGasStation mservice;
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable= new CompositeDisposable();
    RecyclerView ls_combustible;
    TextView txt_banner_name;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_combustibl);
        mservice=Station.getApi();

        ls_combustible=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_combustibles);
        ls_combustible.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
        ls_combustible.setHasFixedSize(true);
        txt_banner_name=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.banner_comb);
        loadListCombustible(Station.currentGrifos.ID);

    }

    private void loadListCombustible(String grifoid) {


        compositeDisposable.add(mservice.getCombustible(grifoid)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Combustible>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<Combustible> combustibles) throws Exception {

                        displayCombustibleList(combustibles);
                    }
                }));
    }

    private void displayCombustibleList(List<Combustible> combustibles) {
        CombustibleAdapter adapter= new CombustibleAdapter(this,combustibles);
        ls_combustible.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

y el error que me genera es el siguiente:

> ```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: google.cajamarca.peru.appgasstation, PID: 3719
> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
>     at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:704)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:701)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError(LambdaObserver.java:77)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>     at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
>     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:350)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:80)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
>     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
>     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
>     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
>     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
>     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
>     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:41)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
>     at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
>     at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11040)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
>     at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
>     at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta al problema se especifica en el mensaje de error:

> Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

incida en español

> Se esperaba obtener un ARRAY pero fue un OBJECT en la línea 1 columna
>   2 ruta $

---

El problema se genera al realizar la petición `POST`, en el cual defines que esperas obtener una lista o array de objetos `Conbustible`:

```
...
...
 @POST("getcombustible.php")
 io.reactivex.Observable<List<Combustible>> 
...
...
```

por lo tanto la estructura que de la respuesta al realizar la petición `POST` debes ser de esta forma:

```
[
  {
   ...
   ...  
  },
  ...
  ...
]
```

Tu pregunta puedes ser un duplicado de esta:

[Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151426/expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object-at-line-1-column-2-path)

Pero en este caso tu objeto necesita indicar que valores de tu JSON necesitan ser serializados, para eso debes modificar tu objeto :

```
public class Combustible {
    @SerializedName("ID");
    public int ID;
    @SerializedName("Categoria");
    public String Categoria;
    @SerializedName("Descripcion");
    public String Descripcion;
    @SerializedName("Precio");
    public double Precio;
    @SerializedName("Banner");
    public String Banner;
    @SerializedName("GrifoId");
    public int GrifoId;

    public Combustible() {
    }

    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return Precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        Precio = precio;
    }

    public void setID(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public int getGrifoId() {
        return GrifoId;
    }

    public void setGrifoId(int grifoId) {
        GrifoId = grifoId;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return Categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        Categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return Descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        Descripcion = descripcion;
    }



    public String getBanner() {
        return Banner;
    }

    public void setBanner(String banner) {
        Banner = banner;
    }



    public  String getImageUrl(){
        return "http://192.168.76.1:8080/gasolinera/Combutibles/"+this.Categoria+this.Descripcion+".jpg";
    }
}
```